# How to remove all special Characters from a string except - . and space

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string where I want to remove all special characters except hyphen , a dot and space.

I am using `filename.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]","")`. It is working for `.` and `-` but not for space.

What should I add to this to make it work for space as well?

Comment: Did you tried my answer?

Comment: Your updated answer worked for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either `\s` or simply a space character  as explained in the [`Pattern` class javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

```
\s - A whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]
   - Literal space character
```

You must either escape `-` character as `\-` so it won't be interpreted as range expression or make sure it stays as the last regex character. Putting it all together:

```
filename.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s.-]", "")
filename.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 .-]", "")
```

Comment: I did this  **filename.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9.-\s]","")**
and got this error Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: @Nirpeksh updated, you need to properly escape `\s` and `-`

Comment: Keep in mind that `\s` represents whitespacing. If you only want to keep spaces I wouldn't use `\s` since it also matches: horizontal and vertical tabs, newline and carriage return characters, etc.

Comment: What should i use if i only want to keep spaces?

Comment: use literal space character `filename.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 .-]", "")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex `[^a-zA-Z0-9\s.-]` or `[^a-zA-Z0-9 .-]`

`\s` matches whitespace and  (space character) matches only space.

So in this case if you want to match whitespaces use this:

```
filename.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s.-]", "");
```

And if you want only match space use this:

```
filename.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 .-]", "");
```

Comment: A "space" is a whitespace but not all whitespace are "space". So this might be a problem.

Comment: @AxelH you are right but I think he need whitespace not only space!

Comment: @AxelH I edited my answer to cover your claim, tnx :)

Comment: That's covering both solution, better ! +1